# How to check a statement with different values in the group?

Tags: regex

The group values are `(a|b|c)` what is the regex will give me these outputs for these statements:

```
a   (True)
a,b (True)
b,c (True)
b,c,a (True)

a,   (false) -no value after ','
a,a (false) -Repeated values
b,b (false) -Repeated values
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please clarify it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This will match a,a and b.b, won't it?

Comment: @ChrisLear: Sure, the lookahead is necessary.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? As in, what programming language is the regex being used in?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c` just letters or multicharacter strings?

Comment: I wanna to match a,b and b,c or a only, but not match the repeated such a,a or b,b

Comment: Is `a` a letter `a`, or can it stand for `alpha`? Have you tried your hand at it already, BTW?

Comment: yes a, b, c just letters

Comment: You know you can do it without a regex in C#, don't you? Why did you choose a regex if you do not know regex?

Comment: Because user will write a lot of texts at the program under some roles like this a,b=8% c,d=10% f=5% ..etc and other roles and i don't wanna to use many controls only textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex preventing duplicates **and** trailing commas.

```
/^(?:([abc]),(?!.*\1))*([abc])$/gm
```

It test for an **optional** group containing a character followed by a comma. Within the group - use negative look-ahead to make sure the same character doesn't repeat it self on the line. This group may repeat any number of times. Finally test for the final character (not optional).

[Example regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/lI2qT8/1)

Regards

Edit:

In answer to a question in a comment - here's how you could do the same with tokens/words:

```
^(?:(cat|dog|rat),(?!.*\1))*(cat|dog|rat)$
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/lI2qT8/2).

It's basically the same regex but using words with alternation instead of character classes.

Comment: `/^(?:(:?,?([abc]))(?!.*\1))*$/gm` is a tiny bit shorter, and I think otherwise similar.

Comment: @ChrisLear That may start with a comma though, which I guess isn't OK.

Comment: I really like how easy it is to change what the letters it searches for are.

Comment: I used this regex to create a cool little fiddle! See my answer also. https://jsfiddle.net/Lkos0tfa/4/

Comment: How would you adapt this regex to search for multi-character tokens instead?

Comment: @4castle Off the top of my head, change the character class `[abc]` - allowing `a`, `b` or `c`, to alternation e.g. `cat|dog|rat` with `/^(?:(cat|dog|rat),(?!.*\1))*(cat|dog|rat)$/gm` as resulting regex.

Comment: Seems to work :) - [example](https://regex101.com/r/lI2qT8/2)

Comment: Great man , Thanks for u

Comment: That exactly what I need,Many Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a coma-sperated list of groups in the set {a, b, c}, but you do not want any additional trailing comas. I suppose you also do not want missing elements (consecutive comas).

I propose this:

```
^([a|b|c],)*[a|b|b]$
```

And propose a little explanation:

- The first part `([A-Za-z]+,)*` searches for alpha elements **each followed by a comma.**. There can be any number of these elements. These are the 1,2 , 3...n-1 elements of the list of n elements.
- Then this last part `[a|b|c]` looks for a **final** element.
- The whole string is surrounded by `^[stuff]$` to impose the regex to match the whole input string, from start to end.

Try it [here](http://regexr.com/%20regexr.com). (I'm not affiliated to this site)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Just sow that you do not want duplicates. Tough luck I don't see this being possible. I would suggest using the above, then scanning once for `.*a.*` then for `.*b.*`, finally for `.*c.*`and request the number of matches of the last 3 scans be <1

Comment: This matches duplicates. Not correct

Comment: but this will give me a repeated alpha such a,a or b,b :(

Comment: I guess all the upvotes are for the fact that there are a lot of words, rather than because it works

Comment: Many thanks Sylvain Boisse

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not the only way to solve this problem.

If you would like to see how to do this without a regex, here is a bit of JavaScript code that demonstrates how you could do it. If you want to see a full demonstration of it head to head with the regex by ClasG, **[here's a cool little fiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkos0tfa/4/)**.

```
var regexReplacement = function(input) {
  var acceptableStrings = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var arr = input.split(",");
  if (arr.indexOf("") == -1 && (new Set(arr)).size == arr.length) {
    return arr.every(function(val) {
      return acceptableStrings.some(function(acceptable) {
        return val === acceptable;
      });
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: In case you're curious, I found that my function averaged at about *0.2141* ms and the regex averaged at about *0.2134 ms*.

Comment: I don't really expect this to be any better or worse than using regex, I'm just giving an alternative for the sake of being thorough.

Comment: Many thanks my friend